# Ant emma test with android "Could not find file coverage.em to delete."

Tags: java, android, ant, emma

I'm trying to get code coverage set up for my android project with Ant and Emma, and I have the project successfully building, the tests successfully running, and the coverage.ec file generating, but the coverage reports aren't being generated. When I ran `ant -verbose emma test` I got the following clues:

```
[report] nothing to do: no metadata found in any of the data files
...
[delete] Could not find file /path/to/my/testProject/bin/coverage.em to delete.
```

I'm using the default build.xml file generated by the android command line tool, which imports a very large build.xml file from the {sdk.dir}/tools/ant directory. I've compared the info there to snippets I've found online and everything seems to be in order. What am I missing? How do I generate the coverage.em file?

Answer (score 1):

I get the coverage report successfully by following steps:

0.install ant on my system

1.(in the sdk/tools dir)

```
android update project -p <path to app project>
```

2.(in the sdk/tools dir)

```
android update test-project -m <path to app project> -p <path to test project>
```

3.(in the test project root dir)

```
ant clean emma debug install test
```

4.the report is /bin/coverage.html